# Laravel 5.1 Eager Loading - belongsToMany with parameter

Tags: php, orm, laravel-5.1, relationship, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have this relationship in my Model:

```
public function modulesData($module) {
    return $this->belongsToMany($module)
        ->withTimestamps();
}
```

What I want is to eagerload a dynamic relation of my model. But how can I do this? 
I use this code to eagerload my relation, but how can I add the parameter `$module`?

```
$model->with(['modulesData'])->get();
```

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Wow, I didn't even know you could pass a parameter to your relationship.

Comment: yes it works with parameters.. I even need this because I work with dynamic module relation of my models.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following:

Define the fallback function to your Model:

```
public function __call($name, $arguments)
{
    if (strpos($name, 'modulesData') !== false) {
        $nameArray = explode(' ', $name);
        $moduleName = ucfirst($nameArray[1]);
        $moduleClass = 'App\Modules\\' . $moduleName . '\\' . $moduleName;
        return $this->modulesData($moduleClass);
    } else {
        return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Use the `with` function with this way:

```
$tal = \App\Model::with('modulesData ModuleName')->get();
```

(being 'ModuleName' the name of the module you want to use as parameter for the relationship).

This way you can eagerload with the string "`modulesData_moduleName`". When `with` is invoked it won't find that function and will fallback to `__call`, which will extract the "moduleName" and call the relationship "modulesData" with it as parameter.

Comment: this is an interesting approach .. but this will not work, because there is already a __call function in the laravel model class. (vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php) ...
I got the error "Call to a member function orderBy() on null"

Comment: @goldlife No problem: Updated with call to parent::_call in case it doesn't match what we are looking for

Comment: hm also error: "Call to a member function orderBy() on boolean" .. instead of "Call to a member function orderBy() on null"

Comment: Your code provides the approach for the solution. It works now with this code:
public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        if (strpos($name,'modulesData') !== false) {
            $nameArray = explode('_', $name);
            $moduleName = ucfirst($nameArray[1]);
            $moduleClass = 'App\Modules\\'.$moduleName.'\\'.$moduleName;
            return $this->modulesData($moduleClass);
        } else {
            return parent::__call($name, $arguments);
        }
    }
the return false is wrong in your code. It has to be return parent::_call. please change it, I will accept it.

Comment: @goldlife You got it.

Comment: @goldlife Oh, minor change in the code of your comment: the delimiter in the comment was empty, replaced in the code of the answer with an espace. And also replaced the underscore in the `with` call with another espace. Team work!

Answer (score -1):

I dont know how to pass parameters but you could do something like:

```
$model->with(['modulesData' => function($q) {
    $q->withTimestamps();
}])->get();
```